# WHERE EXISTS not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I need to delete few records which I got from a subquery.

Let's say that the `EMP` table has columns `EMPNAME`, `EMPSALARY` and the primary key is a combination of `EMPNAME,EMPSALARY`.

```
DELETE FROM EMP E1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT E2 
              FROM EMP E2 
              WHERE E1.EMPNAME = E2.EMPNAME 
              AND E1.EMPSALARY = '100' 
              AND E2.EMPSALARY = '1000');
```

The above query works with ORACLE but gives:

> Incorrect syntax near E1.

with SQL Server. I need to write a query which is compatible with both.

Comment: "*but failing*" is not a valid error message in SQL Server (and: don't compare apples to oranges. `'100'` is a character literal, not a number `100` is a number)

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem in aliasing which you are using. Try this

```
DELETE E1
FROM EMP E1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
              FROM EMP E2 
              WHERE E2.EmpName =  E1.EmpName
              AND E1.EMPSALARY = '100' 
              AND E2.EMPSALARY = '1000');
```

In T-Sql aliasing goes like this-

```
Delete f from dbo.Foo as f where exists(------)
```

Comment: Hi Mukund, your query works with SQLSERVER, what i need is some thing which work with both ORACLE and SQLSERVER.

Comment: is this query not working with oracle? if no you can try joins.

Answer (score 0):

The outer and inner queries aren't related in any way, which is usually dangerous and can lead to the entire table being wiped out.

Besides, this syntax will not work in SQL Server, you need to change it slightly:

```
DELETE e1 --Here is the difference
FROM EMP E1
where E1.EMPNAME = US2.EMPNAME --WTH this alias came from?
AND E1.EMPSALARY = 100
and EXISTS (SELECT E2 FROM EMP E2 WHERE E2.EMPSALARY = 1000);
```

Not sure whether it will still be viable for Oracle, though.